# C# In-memory database. Nested entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm using an in-memory database and Entity Framework for unit testing. In the test method, I added several entities (for example, two) to the main:

```
var user = fixture.Build<User>().Create();
await context.Users.AddAsync(user);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var game = fixture.Build<Game>().With(x => x.User, user)
        .With(x => x.Name, item.Name).With(x => x.Weight, item.Weight).Create();
    await context.Games.AddAsync(game);
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In the business logic of the tested method I fetch only one game with the heaviest weight:

```
var user = await context.Users
                        .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                        .Include(x => x.Games
                                       .OrderByDescending(y => y.Weight)
                                       .Take(1))
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But in the end, `user.Games` contain all entities (two). Because of this, the test falls.

Is there any way to avoid this without changing the business logic? Thank you

Comment: I"user.Games contains all entities (two)". Why does this cause your test to fail? It sounds reasonable... what is the test? Why does it matter how many entities are in user.Games?

Comment: Because response should contain the values of only this entity (game with the heaviest weight). Then the automapper is used

Comment: As it stands it is not clear what is wrong. Needs more information I guess. I don't see any test here so don't know what you mean when you say it fails the test.

Comment: Sorting by weight doesn't occur and further calculations happen with the wrong entity

Comment: Okay I see what you mean - but no idea. I've never tried that with EF. It would be interesting to try to see what SQL it generates.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are expecting the in-memory database provider to behave exactly the same as the SQL provider. Unfortunately it does not, and it appears that conditional includes are something that it is not managing. Unit testing around DbContexts is messy which is a justification for patterns like Repositories to abstract rather than trying to mock a DbContext/DbSet or relying on substituting the Database /w an in-memory provider which won't be 100% compatible.